# Attach the extracted metadata to original file

Tags: image, video, exiftool, exiv2

I have some files from which i removed the metadata and extracted it in YML file using exiftool. Now i want to attach those files again to same files. I tried EXIV2 but its not working. Is there any tool or specific command to make it work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a few YML to JSON converters online.  If it's only a few files, then you could convert the YML files to JSON, and then then import the data with

`ExifTool -Json=/path/to/JSON_File /path/to/target/file`

Though I now see that you have a video tag on this and ExifTool only has limited support for video files.

Comment: I am getting this error:  `No SourceFile entries in '/Users/l375h4ck/Desktop/test1.json'
No SourceFile '/Users/l375h4ck/Desktop/Screen Shot 2015-04-10 at 3.52.33 PM.png' in imported JSON database
(full path: '/Users/l375h4ck/Desktop/Screen Shot 2015-04-10 at 3.52.33 PM.png')`

Comment: It appears that ExifTool needs a sourcefile entry.  Sorry about that, it's not an aspect of ExifTool that I've worked with yet.

  In the json file, you could add something like
`"SourceFile": "/Users/l375h4ck/Desktop/Screen Shot 2015-04-10 at 3.52.33 PM.png"`
and see if that works.

Comment: Hmmm...  Is `/Users/l375h4ck/Desktop/Screen Shot 2015-04-10 at 3.52.33 PM.png` the proper path to the file?  Rereading the error message seems to indicate that ExifTool can't find the file.  You might also try posting over at the [ExifTool forums](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php).  The author is very active with helping people with the program.